# Shortest possible good codes?

Tags: it.information-theory, coding-theory

Good codes (those with positive rate $r=k/n$ and positive relative distance $\delta=d/n$) will achieve capacity on $BSC$ (binary symmetric channel) if the codes have lower rates than capacity where positive relative distance is seen. However this requires very long codes to drive the error to reasonably low value.

To achieve an error rate of $e$ if capacity is $C$ then what is the shortest good code that is possible over $BSC$ as a function of $e$? I am just looking for an upper bound and a lower bound.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but exactly what is the capacity of a code, and what do you mean by "where positive relative distance is seen"?

Comment: Capacity is maximum rate supported for negligible error communication over a channel.

Comment: capacity is a property of the *channel* not  the code

Comment: Please tell where the discrepancy is.

Comment: my comment was to clarify capacity in response to @W-t-P

Comment: To clarify: When you say "to achieve a (relative?) error rate $e$", do you mean "to be able to correct up to $t$ errors, where $t/n \leq e$?"

Comment: No average bit error in your ensemble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upper and lower bounds as well as approximations are given in "Channel Coding Rate in the Finite Blocklength Regime" by Yury Polyanskiy, H. Vincent Poor, and Sergio Verdu.